# Invoke Python script (in machine#1) from NodeJS(in machine#2)

Tags: rpc, nodejs-server

I want to invoke Python script (Present in machine#1) from NodeJS Application (Present in machine#2, which is the web hosting server). Pls let me know how in terms of

1. What packages are to be installed in NodeJS application (Machine #2) & what API/RPCs to call with certain parameters to be passed to Machine #1
2. What service must be running in Machine #1 so that Machine#1 accepts the Invoke Command from Machine #2. What commands do I run to invoke the Python script

Note: I am assuming that the requirement for Machine#1 must be a static IP address, where the NodeJS application can always invoke via the static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ssh on your machine1 I would do it with SSH. Assuming you don't need a pipeline. You can use spawn or exec in node to run something like

ssh user@10.0.0.1 "python /path/to/script.py"

Answer (score 0):

simply you can create a flask application on Machine #1
and run it as a service

then when you want to invoke the function from Machine #2 with nodeJS
you can send a GET or POST request to Machine #1
and flask will run the function or the script you want and return the result to Machine #2

https://flask.palletsprojects.com

https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs